# Search secondary array by matching value and merge into primary array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays, I am trying to find array objects in the second array that match the Id from an object in the first array. From there I need to append the matching objects to the primary object. I also need to only take the top 3 matching objects by a key value. I have been trying with Underscore but this only merges the matching arrays together. Heres is what I need to achieve, any help would be great.

```
var primaryArray = [
  {
    "Name": "Main 1",
    "Id": "1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Main 2",
    "Id": "2"
  }
]


var secondaryArray = [
  {
    "name": "Person 1",
    "mainitemId": "1",
    "count": 120
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 2",
    "mainitemId": "1",
    "count": 80
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 3",
    "mainitemId": "1",
    "count": 125
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 4",
    "mainitemId": "1",
    "count": 130
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 5",
    "mainitemId": "2",
    "count": 90
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 6",
    "mainitemId": "2",
    "count": 85
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 7",
    "mainitemId": "2",
    "count": 105
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 8",
    "mainitemId": "2",
    "count": 110
  }
]


var resultArray = [
  {
    "Name": "Main 1",
    "Id": 1,
    "people": [
      {
        "name": "Person 4",
        "mainitemId": "1",
        "count": 130
      },
      {
        "name": "Person 3",
        "mainitemId": "1",
        "count": 125
      },
      {
        "name": "Person 1",
        "mainitemId": "1",
        "count": 120
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Main 2",
    "Id": 2,
    "people": [
      {
        "name": "Person 8",
        "mainitemId": "2",
        "count": 110
      },
      {
        "name": "Person 7",
        "mainitemId": "2",
        "count": 105
      },
      {
        "name": "Person 5",
        "mainitemId": "2",
        "count": 90
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: You are looking for several things, merging arrays, searching by object value and possibly sorting to determine top 3 (**What determines top3?**). There is plenty of examples on the web how to do each part. Pick one and try it out. If you have issues with the code, post it here and we look at it. Also, see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, if applicable, using your own code you are having issues with, [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the top 3 based on *count* value, it should be ...

```
var result = primaryArray.map(item => {
    item.people = secondaryArray.filter(peop => peop.mainitemId === item.Id)
                                .sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)
                                .slice(0, 3);
    return item;        
})
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Faly that is perfect and saved me a headache, I had been trying _.map > _.extend >_.findWhere but wasn't giving me the first part of the result I needed!

Comment: You're welcome !